# Damaged passport - will it be acceptable?

Tags: uk, damaged-passports

So my Polish passport's first ID page is falling out and becoming detached; it’s still attached but is coming undone.

Apart from that, it's in perfect condition; all details are readable, it’s just it's holding on to the glue and becoming detached.

I’m traveling in 2 weeks. Would it still be acceptable?

I’ll be traveling from England to Portugal.

Comment: How much is it falling out? Does the ID page even remotely look as though it has been tampered with – replaced? Please post a picture with the details blocked out.

Comment: Loose binding could be a reason for an airline and/or border officials to deem a passport to be damaged. If you’re unsure, better to assume it’s too damaged and replace it.

Comment: Earl Grey - Since Brexit, EU ID cards can only be used to enter the UK by people holding EU Settled Status (and only until 2025)

Comment: @canonacer thanks, very important point to say explicitly. I assumed OP was resident in the UK (why? I do not know, maybe I read too quickly the question)

Answer (score 1):

In general, it's best to get it replaced if possible.  I don't know what an expedited passport book process might look like in Poland.  If you're currently in the UK, it might be best to check with your consulate to ask for an emergency book (if this is offered to Polish passport holders).

A quick fix, which should work, in theory, is just to apply a very small amount of adhesive that wouldn't be overly noticeable to the seam and try to fix the page a little better.

You just never know with immigration.  I have a passport book that went through a washing machine (yeah.....).  I've been "nomadic" for over five years, and don't care to sit and count the number of countries right now.  Point is, even with stamps washed out in some parts, and a weakened binding, I've only had two immigration officers out of.... countless, make any sort of comment.  I simply tell them no one else has commented, and I have not had a chance to get a new book (essentially true on both accounts).  They usually flip through and see all the stamps (if anything, I'll need a new book at some point for more pages), and sort of shrug.

I would also think returning to Poland on a Polish passport will make things easier for you.  I would think you're far less likely to be criticized than a foreign national in the same situation.  You could always get a new book at home, as well, after re-entering.

Best wishes!

Comment: *You could always get a new book at home, as well, after re-entering.* Consulates and embassies can do the same, without the need of going back home...

Comment: *just to apply a very small amount of adhesive that wouldn't be overly noticeable to the seam and try to fix the page a little better.*
This is 99% sure to backfire. Did you try yourself? Consider yourself part of the lucky 1% :) !

Comment: Yes, I have downvoted this answer due to that terrible advice. Honestly if they see your passport as suspicious and then look carefully and notice the ID page appears to be glued in, you'll be in for a tough time.

Answer (score -4):

If you are polish and currently legally residing in the UK, your national polish ID is enough to travel to/from the UK.

EDIT: apologize for letting out an important part (I thought it was obvious from the question that OP is residing in the UK, but I understand it is not the case)

Comment: @Tom Air carrier are not required to perform check on immigration status https://ima-citizensrights.org.uk/news_events/watchdog-concerned-that-airline-carriers-are-stopping-some-eu-and-eea-efta-citizens-from-travelling/
You can fly with a national ID ... sure, you may be denied entering in the country if you do not have the correct document, but a polish ID is good to go to enter Portugal.

Comment: And if the are a UK resident, with the required residence permit (BRP) they can use their Polish ID to reenter the UK.